# How to scrape review to dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, beautifulsoup

I would like to scratch the reviews from this [page](https://www.morele.net/pralka-candy-cs4-1062d3-950636/?sekcja=reviews-all) and save them as a data frame, but I do not download star ratings and the text of the review. Just only text. What i did wrong?

```
import csv
import pandas as pd
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

page = requests.get("https://www.morele.net/pralka-candy-cs4-1062d3-950636/?sekcja=reviews-all")

soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, "html.parser",
).find_all("div", {"class":"reviews-item"}) 
# print(soup)
morele = [div.getText(strip=True) for div in soup]

print(morele)
csv_table = pd.DataFrame(morele)
csv_table = csv_table.reset_index(drop=True)
csv_table.insert(0,'No.',csv_table.index)
```

Comment: You have to select the rating in `div` with `class="stars-box  "` separat, wont get it with `get_text()` - figure out what describe the full, half and empty stars,...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are mostly there - just further navigate the DOM and you can get just the text.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

page = requests.get("https://www.morele.net/pralka-candy-cs4-1062d3-950636/?sekcja=reviews-all")

soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, "html.parser",) 

data = [{"text":ri.find("div", {"class":"rev-desc"}).getText(strip=True) ,
        "stars":ri.find("div", {"class":"rev-stars"}).getText(strip=True)}
 for ri in soup.find_all("div", {"class":"reviews-item"})
]

pd.DataFrame(data)
```

Comment: Thanks, but i got only description of review without raiting from star

Comment: Could you help me with it ?

Comment: as I noted,  you are there, just navigate the DOM.  I find chrome best for this,  also sometime use safari